# DocuSign embed UI via AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, docusignapi

We are working on a serverless document manager using AWS.

Is it possible to integrate DocuSign embed-UI (link below) with JWT token by just using Lambda & other serverless components via Node.js?

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/embed-ui/

Or is there any Angular JS solution that we can integrate completely on the frontend?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is:

1. Single page app front end (React / Angular / etc) with a serverless backend (AWS Lambda)
2. How to authenticate with DocuSign so the signing ceremony can be shown on the front end?
3. The signers on the front end do not have DocuSign accounts--as signers they don't need such accounts.

### Answer

Because of issues 2 and 3, JWT grant is the way to go. The overall application will *impersonate* a system user such as doc_manager@example.com. That system user will be used to obtain the embedded signing ceremony URL from the DocuSign API.

#### Can JWT grant be managed by Lambda functions?

I haven't tried, but I think it should work ok:

1. When a Lambda func needs a DocuSign access token it would look in stable storage for an access token that hasn't expired (a database or other storage that is maintained across Lambda invocations). Access tokens from JWT grant last an hour.
2. If an access token is available, it is used. **END**
3. If an access token is not available or expired, the Lambda would initiate the JWT grant flow. That takes a couple of seconds.
4. The resulting access token is stored in the stable storage and is used by the function to call the DocuSign API. **END**

#### Notes:

1. If the app will be using multiple DocuSign user accounts, then the app will maintain multiple access tokens, one per impersonated user/account.
2. Don't create a new access token unless the old one is near (within 10 minutes) its expiration or has expired. There are limits on the number of outstanding access tokens, plus the JWT grant flow is slow.
3. Since the access tokens represent user access, safeguard them appropriately!

#### The front end

When the URL for the DocuSign signing ceremony is received from the back end, either redirect the browser to the URL, or open a new tab to the URL. Don't use an iFrame.

Comment: Thanks Larry, we needed to make some changes to the Docusign code to make it better suited to be used with the AWS Lambda. And all seems to be working now.